# how to fetch json nested data from api url

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my json export data

```
{
"count":79,
"stories":{
  "23658975":{
     "title":"NOMINATIVO",
     "description":"BUSDRAGHI PIERGIORGIO",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:55:56+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:06+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":14,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23658975",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658965"
  },
  "23658985":{
     "title":"SOGGETTO",
     "description":"PRIVATO",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:55:56+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:06+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":15,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23658985",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658965"
  },
  "23658995":{
     "title":"CF/P.IVA",
     "description":"BSD PRG 77P19 G999C",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:55:56+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:06+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":16,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23658995",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658965"
  },
  "23659005":{
     "title":"DOMICILIO o SEDE LEGALE",
     "description":"Via NOMEVIA, xx - LOCALITA CAP COMUNE (PR)",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:55:56+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:06+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":17,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23659005",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658965"
  },
  "23659015":{
     "title":"LEGALE RAPPRESENTANTE",
     "description":"-",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-21T00:46:56+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:06+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":18,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23659015",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658965",
     "sub_story_ids":[

     ]
  },
  "23658885":{
     "title":"INCARICO N.",
     "description":"22999",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:47:50+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:05+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":5,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23658885",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658875"
  },
  "23658895":{
     "title":"DATA INCARICO",
     "description":"12 Giugno 2013",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:47:50+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:05+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":6,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23658895",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658875"
  },
  "23658905":{
     "title":"NUMERO SINISTRO",
     "description":"721234567-1",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:47:50+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:05+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":7,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23658905",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658875"
  },
  "23658915":{
     "title":"DATA SINISTRO",
     "description":"1/5/13",
     "updated_at":"2013-06-16T18:47:50+02:00",
     "created_at":"2013-06-16T18:39:05+02:00",
     "due_date":null,
     "start_date":null,
     "story_type":"task",
     "state":"not started",
     "position":8,
     "archived":false,
     "deleted_at":null,
     "sub_story_count":0,
     "budget_estimate_in_cents":null,
     "time_estimate_in_minutes":null,
     "budget_used_in_cents":0,
     "logged_billable_time_in_minutes":0,
     "id":"23658915",
     "workspace_id":"3190675",
     "parent_id":"23658875"
  }, ... and so on ... (check the api url blow for full file)
```

The export file is generated automatically via an API url, so i can't modify the json structure. Here is the full json file http://www.studiokaleya.it/mavenlinkapi/dati/stories.json

Here is what i would like to do:

1. A web page with a fillable field for the api url workspace_id value and button to automatically generate the search on the api
2. Fetch data from json and report "title" and report "description" values in html tables

Scratch table example:

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>NUMERO SINISTRO</TD>
<TD>DATA SINISTRO</TD>
<TD>MORE DATA>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>here goes "description" value for "NUMERO SINISTRO"</TD>
<TD>here goes "description" value for "DATA SINISTRO"</TD>
<TD>and so on...</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

A little bit far beyond my capabilities ... so any specific hint may help.

Comment: You example link requires authentication could you provide an example of your data with a public URL?

Comment: Here is the complete file [link](http://www.studiokaleya.it/mavenlinkapi/dati/stories.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of [this page](http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/) and see how you get on. Particularly the section "Reading JSON from an external file"

Comment: Clear hint and it works. Now how to get "title" and "description" values and post them to specific hmtl template positions?